# C# - Excel: Chart automation

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I want to make a Chart automatically in Excel from C#

This is the Table:

[image: Table]

This is maybe a litte bit confusing, "A" is @B11, "1" is @A12 and so on ;)

This is my Code

```
Excel.Range ChartRangeThree;
Excel._Chart ChartThree;
Excel.Series oSeriesThree;
ChartThree = (Excel._Chart)oWB.Charts.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
ChartRangeThree = oSheetThree.get_Range("A11:E15").get_Resize(5,5);
ChartThree.ChartWizard(ChartRangeThree, Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn, Missing.Value, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows);
oSeriesThree = (Excel.Series)ChartThree.SeriesCollection(1);
oSeriesThree.XValues = oSheetThree.get_Range("B11", "E11");
ChartThree.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, oSheetThree.Name);
```

Now this is what I get:

[image: Chart]

That is nice so far, but I just want the values from "D" to be compared in a Chart.

EDIT:

A Workaround would be to make a local table like this:

[image]

To make a chart like this:

[image]

And delete the table afterwards, but thats not a nice way to do is...

Comment: Whats the problem with it?

Comment: The chart displays the data from "A", "B", "C" and "D", I just want to display the data from "D" in the chart

Comment: @jochot what you get is different to [**what I get using your code**](http://s17.postimg.org/r7zsjx2fj/Untitled.png)?

Comment: @mehow That looks like there is no Data in A,B and D in your Table?

Comment: well, what do you actually want to do? can you show a finished chart the way you want it?

Comment: @mehow, in the moment you asked I edited the question with a workaround ;)

Comment: seems like all you need is to just modify the ranges for the chart

Comment: If I change the ranges like this `ChartRangeThree = oSheetThree.get_Range("E11:E15").get_Resize(5,1);` I get a totally wrong Chart with data from another Sheet in the Workbook and I don't understand why ...